# Turning several individual dictionaries into a list of dictionaries in PYTHON

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have written a code to return information in the form of dictionaries as follows:

```
{'Mean Temp': '-0.1', 'Total Rain': '45', 'Month': '12', 'Year': '2003', 'Total Snow': '19.2', 'Max Temp': '-10.8', 'Min Temp': '9'}

{'Mean Temp': '-5.9', 'Total Rain': '34.3', 'Month': '1', 'Year': '1974', 'Total Snow': '35.6', 'Max Temp': '-20', 'Min Temp': '8.9'}

{'Mean Temp': '22.4', 'Total Rain': '20.8', 'Month': '8', 'Year': '2007', 'Total Snow': '0', 'Max Temp': '9.7', 'Min Temp': '34.8'}

{'Mean Temp': '21.7', 'Total Rain': '87.7', 'Month': '7', 'Year': '1993', 'Total Snow': '0', 'Max Temp': '11', 'Min Temp': '32.5'}

{'Mean Temp': '15.2', 'Total Rain': '112.5', 'Month': '6', 'Year': '1982', 'Total Snow': '0', 'Max Temp': '4', 'Min Temp': '25.4'}
```

I need to know how to turn these separate dictionaries into a single list separating them all by commas.  My code so far:

```
    listData = weatherData.split("\n")
    i = 0
    for listData[i] in listData :
        newList = listData[i].split(",")
        i = i + 1
        newDict = dict({'Year': newList[0], 'Month': newList[1], 'Mean Temp': 
                        newList[2], 'Min Temp':newList[3], 'Max Temp':newList[4], 
                        'Total Rain': newList[5], 'Total Snow': newList[6]})
        temp = []
        dictList = []
        i = 0
        for i in newDict :
            temp = [i]
            i = i + 1
            dictList = dictList.append(temp)
            print(dictList)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the final output should look like?

Comment: I believe what I'm looking for is something like:

Comment: [{'Mean Temp': '-0.1', 'Total Rain': '45', 'Month': '12', 'Year': '2003', 'Total Snow': '19.2', 'Max Temp': '-10.8', 'Min Temp': '9'}, {'Mean Temp': '-5.9', 'Total Rain': '34.3', 'Month': '1', 'Year': '1974', 'Total Snow': '35.6', 'Max Temp': '-20', 'Min Temp': '8.9'}...]

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there; you need to move `dictList = []` *out* of the outer `for` loop, and you should not assign the result of `dictlist.append` to `dictlist`, as that'll set the variable to `None`.

You really overcomplicated your code though, it can be simplified to:

```
dictList = []

for entry in weatherData.splitlines():
    newList = entry.split(",")
    newDict = {'Year': newList[0], 'Month': newList[1], 'Mean Temp': 
                    newList[2], 'Min Temp':newList[3], 'Max Temp':newList[4], 
                    'Total Rain': newList[5], 'Total Snow': newList[6]}
    dictList.append(newDict)
```

or even:

```
dictList = []
fields = ('Year', 'Month', 'Mean Temp', 'Min Temp', 'Max Temp', 'Total Rain', 'Total Snow')

for entry in weatherData.splitlines():
    newList = entry.split(",")
    newDict = dict(zip(fields, newList))
    dictList.append(newDict)
```

I suspect that your input file is a CSV file, in which case you may want to use the `csv` module instead:

```
import csv

fields = ('Year', 'Month', 'Mean Temp', 'Min Temp', 'Max Temp', 'Total Rain', 'Total Snow')

with open(yourweatherdatafile, 'rb') as weather:
    reader = csv.DictReader(weather, fields=fields)
    dictList = list(reader)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this definitely simplified my code a ton!  However, when I ran it this way it returned a list of "None" instead of appending the newDict to the empty list.  Any idea why?

Comment: @sammfg: What code in specific is listing `None`? The `DictReader` variant?

Answer (score 1):

`ast.literal_eval` is your friend:

```
weatherData = """
{'Mean Temp': '-0.1', 'Total Rain': '45', 'Month': '12', 'Year': '2003', 'Total Snow': '19.2', 'Max Temp': '-10.8', 'Min Temp': '9'}

{'Mean Temp': '-5.9', 'Total Rain': '34.3', 'Month': '1', 'Year': '1974', 'Total Snow': '35.6', 'Max Temp': '-20', 'Min Temp': '8.9'}

{'Mean Temp': '22.4', 'Total Rain': '20.8', 'Month': '8', 'Year': '2007', 'Total Snow': '0', 'Max Temp': '9.7', 'Min Temp': '34.8'}

{'Mean Temp': '21.7', 'Total Rain': '87.7', 'Month': '7', 'Year': '1993', 'Total Snow': '0', 'Max Temp': '11', 'Min Temp': '32.5'}

{'Mean Temp': '15.2', 'Total Rain': '112.5', 'Month': '6', 'Year': '1982', 'Total Snow': '0', 'Max Temp': '4', 'Min Temp': '25.4'}

 """
import ast
list_data = weatherData.splitlines()
list_of_dict = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in list_data if line.strip()]
```

You could probably also use `json.loads(line)` instead of `ast.literal_eval(line)` if you like that better.

Comment: I think the file only contain simple text, not dicts.